# Error: secretOrPrivateKey is not valid key material

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have following block of code which is throwing an error:

> secretOrPrivateKey is not valid key material.

I'm using Node.js v20.11.0.

```
userSchema.methods.generateAccessToken = async function(){
    const payload = {
        _id: this._id,              
        email: this.email,
        username: this.username,
        fullname: this.fullname
    }
    const secret = {secretOrPrivateKey: "onlne-generted-security-key-sha256"}
    const option = {
        expiresIn: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRY
    }
    return await jwt.sign(payload, secret ,option);   
}
```

I have generation secret key with `crypto.createSecretKey(key[, encoding])` as told in [this](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/wiki/Migration-Notes:-v8-to-v9#secrets-public-keys-and-private-keys-must-contain-valid-key-material) article. Still no luck.

Also followed as per jsonwebtoken docs.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was because of the "await" when returning.

```
return jwt.sign(payload, secret ,option);
```

this is the code change.